# jquery does not deliver paramater to the controller function

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following lines of jquery code in my codeigniter view file that gets the form field values and sends them to the `add_emp_performance` function in `employees` controller.

```
    var emp_id = "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>";
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/employees/add_emp_performance/';?>"+emp_id;
    //alert(emp_id); ---> works fine
    //alert(url);  ---> works fine
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //type: "POST",
        url: url,
        //data: 'emp_id='+emp_id+'&title='+title+'&date='+date,
        success: function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert("Performance Saved!");
            }else{
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller employees function add_emp_performance :

```
function add_emp_performance($emp_id){
    echo $emp_id ;exit;
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for Employees::add_emp_performance()

Filename: controllers/employees.php
```

What could be the problem? many thanx!

Comment: What is the value of `url` when the GET request is made?

Answer (score 0):

problem is you missed the data options of ajax where the data is posted

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    data:{'emp_id':emp_id }, //<---here this is data that is posted to the server
    ....
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you don't pass the vairable emp_id with your ajax
Try this: you can pass data in ajax

```
var emp_id = "<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>";
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();
    var url = "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/employees/add_emp_performance/';?>"+emp_id;
    //alert(emp_id); ---> works fine
    //alert(url);  ---> works fine
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data:{'emp_id':emp_id },
        success: function(r){
            if(r==1){
                alert("Performance Saved!");
            }else{
                alert("Error!");
            }
        }
    });
```

And in your controller you can take teh data passed in this mode:

```
function add_emp_performance(){
    echo $this->input->get('emp_id');exit;
```